# How can I do IP whitelisting for a static site hosted in Firebase? / Is there a WAF for Firebase hosting?

Tags: firebase, security, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting

I have a static website hosted in Firebase. I can attach a custom domain to it fine. I would like to restrict access to my site to a certain range of IPs.

I am aware that in GCP Google Cloud Armor can do this. But Cloud Armor only works with a Load Balancer and the load balancer routes traffic only to GCP VMs.(not to a Firebase hosted site)

In AWS, there is a Web Application Firewall that lets you do IP Filtering.

I see GCP has provided links to 3rd Party partners here: https://cloud.google.com/security/partners/

**But my question is what is the best and easiest way to whitelist IPs for a static website hosted in Firebase?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web sites on Firebase Hosting are accessible to everyone. There is no way to block certain users, or IP ranges, from accessing them

Comment: Frank thanks for answering.  Don't you think this is a serious shortcoming? Enterprises would like to restrict access to internal apps to only employees and consultants from a corporate network. While FB hosting is very convenient way to get up and running I can see this shortcoming being a serious stumbling block for internally accessible apps.

Comment: If IP whitelisting is a requirement for your project, Firebase Hosting may not be a good fit. We're always looking how we can improve our products, so I'd recommend you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: Thanks. I opened a feature request and received a response from Firebase team acknowledging that this would be a good feature to have and that they will look into implementing it in the near future.

Comment: Good to hear. For the moment though, my answer is the correct answer: there is no way to restrict access to assets on Firebase Hosting.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the problem is that staging/production might be a good choice with Firebase, but if you cannot make a somewhat restricted hosting for "test", then I think many will completely rethink the hosting - they don't wanna be hosting different environments on different providers. I guess we can write a function to check ip

Comment: I agree with @Spock. It's quite bothering to NOT be able to whitelist a range of IPs for all testing environments. It's a quite known technique for AWS to be able to do just that. It's a pitty that in 2020, Firebase doesn't provide a system to replicate this. Same thing for tracking the locale, with hosting config alone. Again, the workaround is to trigger a function, but it hearts performances + can be money consuming. It doesn't change the fact that I love Firebase and the whole stack. But it still misses some 'basic' features. Hope they can give us ETA for those very soon :)!

Answer (score 2):

Because Firebase is PaaS service, there is no such thing like firewall. By [Firebase launch checklist](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/launch-checklist)

There are only two kind of protection you can do:

## Protect By Authenication

Add whitelisting for your domains to prevent unauthorized usage.

- Whitelist your production domain for browser API keys and client IDs in the Google Developer Console.
- Whitelist your production domain in the Auth tab of the Firebase console panel.

## Protect your data

Because any client can connect to any Firebase, you must write security rules to secure your data.So according to this document [Firebase security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/), it will show you how to  secure your web by secure who can access database.

This blog [Firebase Security & Rules](https://howtofirebase.com/firebase-security-rules-88d94606ce4a) is also a good reference to learn how to secure your Firebase.

Hope this will help you

Comment: Howie thanks for the response. I'm curious to learn about the first option.  Can you point me to some resources? I think it might be a roundabout way to achieve what I'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: Visit https://console.firebase.google.com/

    Select your application and Goto Left menu "Auth"

    Select Tab "SIGN IN METHOD"

    Add your domain in "OAuth redirect domains"

Comment: Ahh! - No thats not what i am looking for. Thank you for responding though. I opened a Feature Request with FB and they responded that this feature is indeed not currently available but will be implmented soon.

Comment: 2020 and I think it's still not implemented, or am I missing something?

Comment: Even more frustrating as App Engine has had this capability for ages https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/creating-firewalls