# Allow admin panel of react-firebase web app to only specific IP addresses?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, backend

I want the page of website (e.g."https:// website-URL/admin") only accessible specific IP addresses.
I use firebase.google.com & Vercel.com etc. for hosting commonly along with NodeJS & React JS for backend.

Comment: Not possible with Firebase Hosting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55447486/8349557

Comment: Did some research around Vercel and I dont think it’s possible with Vercel either. I think you should talk to the customer support at Vercel.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase hosting is delivered through Fastly, when using cloud functions for onCall and onRequest, you can access this from the header `fastly-client-ip`

Otherwise, if it is from the client, you can call a Cloud Function to check it, or do a remote check with a service, but these kinds of checks are purely cosmetic and can be bypassed if someone created a script to override it.

```
import publicIp from "public-ip";

export const getClientIp = async () => await publicIp.v4({
  fallbackUrls: [ "https://ifconfig.co/ip" ]
});
```

npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/public-ip

beyond the above options, this feature is limited and not accessible to you directly within Firebase config.

Comment: is there any shortcut.

Comment: can you make video / blog on step by step process ?

Comment: all you have to do is use `req.headers['fastly-client-ip']` in your HTTP onRequest with cloud functions